# Fixtures and inheritance in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-inheritance

I have a database schema in Symfony like this:

```
Persona:
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
      primer_nombre:  { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      segundo_nombre: { type: string(255) }
      apellido:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      rut:         { type: string(255) }
      email:       { type: string(255) }
      email2:      { type: string(255) } 
      direccion:     { type: string(400) }
      ciudad:        { type: string(255) }
      region:      { type: string(255) }
      pais:     { type: string(255) }
      telefono:       { type: string(255) }
      telefono2:      { type: string(255) }
      fecha_nacimiento:   { type: date }

Alumno:
 inheritance:
    type:          concrete
    extends:       Persona
 columns:
  comentario:  { type: string(255) }
  estado_pago: { type: string(255) }

Alumno_Beca:
 columns:
  persona_id:   { type: integer, primary: true }
  beca_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
 relations:
  Alumno: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: persona_id, foreign: id } 
  Beca: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: beca_id, foreign: id } 

Beca:
 columns:
  nombre:        { type: string(255) }
  monto:      { type: double }
  porcentaje:  { type: double }
  descripcion: { type: string(5000) }
```

As you see, "alumno" has a concrete inheritance from "persona". Now I'm trying to create fixtures for this two tables, and I can't make Doctrine to load them. It gives me this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`eat/alumno__beca`, CONSTRAINT
>   `alumno__beca_persona_id_alumno_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`) REFERENCES
>   `alumno` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Does someone know how to write a fixture for a table inherited from another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem, but when loading fixtures for tables that have relationships, load them individually in an order that does not violate their foreign key constraints: first parent, then child... not everything together. A child record cannot "legally" exist without its parent, if you have defined your relationships in this way, or else the constraint fails.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I started symfony in last weeks and i have problem today with these..

first problem is, your foreign keys must be integer. not integer(3).. should not write fields size if it is a foreign key. And also your code is correct, this is just an info.

second problem is,
you should remove that foreign key indexes on your database table. if it is already created, when you insert-sql again it gives an error.

Comment: Davit, thanks for the answer! My problem was with the foreign keys constraints, but I couldn't erase them from the database, so I altered the load order of the fixtures and it worked!